# Should the [training] tag be nixed in favor of simply [improvement]?

Tags: discussion

Basically what the title says. Both tags mentioned are currently in use, with 3 questions having the [training] tag and 8 having the [improvement] tag. I think the [training] tag is pretty much superfluous, since any question along the lines of "How should I train for *_*_ aspect of chess?" could rightfully/just-as-usefully be tagged as an [improvement] question. Agree? Disagree?

Out of curiosity: If I were to remove the [training] tag from all questions to which it currently applies, would it disappear from the tag list?

Answer (score 3):

Unless/until there are specific questions related to chess training, I think you are correct that the [training](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) tag is superfluous.

However, I do think that chess trainers asking about how to teach kids various elementary mates might use the training tag.  Or, for example, questions about how to train kids to use more time during games, etc.

Similarly, questions about what to eat before a chess game, or how to relax in between two games in a two-a-day tournament might get a training tag.

But general questions about chess improvement should probably only get the improvement tag.

If the training tag were removed, then it would not disappear.  See [for-white](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/for-white) as an example (I removed the tag from the two questions, but it is still in the list)